# How to install Flex Builder 3 - What backend to connect to?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

"What technology best describes the backend that your Flex application will connect to?  "

I've used Flash for a while, now I'm looking to install Flex Builder 3 trial version to try it out and i'm stumped by the above question.  Do I need to install something before i install Flex?

Answer (score 2):

I think that's just for research purposes only. I skipped it/gave a random answer, and I've succesfully connected to many different back-ends with the same installation.

Answer (score 0):

Flex applications can connect to any back-end: Java, .Net, PHP, Python, Ruby, ColdFusion, etc. The simplest way to make the connection is with XML using HTTPService in Flex. However AMF is a better performing option.